# Shortcuts for different keyboard languages

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using different keyboard languages with `Vim`, i.e., Canadian Multilingual, French (Canada) and English (Canada). Instead of changing systematically the keyboard manually, is there exist a way to create shortcuts like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f1</kbd> **(Canadian Multilingual)**, <kbd>ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> **(French (Canada))** and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f3</kbd> **(English (Canada))**?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** If you could respond as a full answer (with picture) in such a way I may understanding well.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to to that with on simple shortcut, i.e., <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: `Super + Space` is the shortcut to switch between keyboard layouts.